# WAN IP change script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to record and compare my WAN IP address changes.

I found a very useful script (sorry, can't remember the author but thank you!), to save IP in a txt file and I changed it a bit to suit my needs. Now, I'd like to search through txt file each time and add message on screen that IP was never used before or is duplicated.

I am not a programmer and would be grateful for any help.

Script below.

```
$ipDetectionUrl = "https://wtfismyip.com/text"  
$IPAddFile = "C:\IP.txt" #absolute path to file that stores the old IP 
record  
$Request = Invoke-WebRequest $ipDetectionUrl  
$IP_new = ($Request.Content.Trim())  
Write-Host "Current IP address: [$IP_new]"  
#Check if old IP record exists  
If(Test-Path "$IPAddFile")  
{  
#Get old IP  
$IP_old = Get-Content "$IPAddFile" -Tail 1  
#Compare IPs  
if(-not($IP_new -eq $IP_old))  
{  
Write-Host "Old IP address: [$IP_old]"              
#Overwrite and update new IP  
$IP_new |  Out-File $IPAddFile -Append  
}  
else  
{"No change"}  
}  
else  
{  
#Create new, as file not found  
$IP_new |  Out-File $IPAddFile  
"File created"  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `If` can have multiple `elseif` with other conditions but only one `else`

Proper formatting with indents for script blocks renders your code better
readable/understandable also for yourself.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\11\17\SO_53351417.ps1

$ipDetectionUrl = "http://api.ipify.org"
$IPAddFile = "C:\IP.txt" #absolute path to file that stores the old IP record

$IP_new = (Invoke-WebRequest $ipDetectionUrl).Content.Trim()
Write-Host "Current IP address: [$IP_new]"

#Check if old IP record exists
If(!(Test-Path $IPAddFile)){
    #Create new, as file not found
    $IP_new | Out-File $IPAddFile -Encoding default
    "File {0} created" -f $IPAddFile
}

#Get all old IPs
$IP_old = Get-Content $IPAddFile

# 1st compare last IP, then other IPs
if($IP_new -eq $IP_old[-1]){
    "No change"
} else {
    if ($IP_old -contains $IP_new) {
        $LinesAgo = $IP_old.Length - [array]::IndexOf($IP_old,$IP_new') ######
        $wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
        $wshell.Popup($IP_new,0,"IPaddress reused",0x0)|Out-Null
        Write-Host "Old IP address reused [$LinesAgo] lines ago: [$IP_new]" #####
    } else {
        Write-Host "New IP address: [$IP_new]"
    }
    # Append new (or reused) IP
    $IP_new |  Out-File $IPAddFile -Append  -Encoding default
}
```

I used `http://api.ipify.org` because it prefers IPv4 over IPv6 addresses.

Comment: Thanks @LotPings, work very well. Is it possible to have a pop up message informing about re used IP?

Comment: There are  several ways to do that, here is one `$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell;$wshell.Popup($IP_new,0,"IPaddress reused",0x0)|out-Null`

Comment: I added below to: if ($IP_old -contains $IP_new) and it seems to work fine. Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
$ButtonType = [System.Windows.MessageBoxButton]::Ok
$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.MessageBoxImage]::Error
$MessageBody = "Old IP address reused: [$IP_new]"
$MessageTitle = "IP Conflict"
$Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($MessageBody,$MessageTitle,$ButtonType,$MessageIcon)

Comment: See changed answer.

Comment: Would you be so kind and let me know if it's possible that on Write-Host "Old IP address reused: [$IP_new]" it would also tell how how many IPs before it was? So something like "Old IP address reused 25 lines ago: [$IP_new]"

Comment: `$IP_old -contains $IP_new` returns just $true/$false, so to evaluate the position **NEW** code is neccessary preferably in a **NEW** question. That answer is 157 days ago and out of my head ;-)

Comment: When you're bored and have nothing better to do, could you try remind yourself please? :-)

Comment: For the calculation you could use `$LinesAgo = $IP_old.Length - [array]::IndexOf($IP_old,$IP_new')` this will find the 1st occurence of `$IP_new` inside `$IP_old`

Comment: Could you advise where exactly the calculation goes? Then, Write-Host "Old IP address reused [$LinesAgo]: [$IP_new]" would work?

Comment: See changed lines with trailing `#####` marker. So I've got the work and no more rep and you the benefit...

Comment: Thank you very much! If I could I would give unlimited rep :-) You are the best mate